# GroupBy.apply vs common aggregation, when trying to assign to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a sample dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'http_user':['user1']*10, 'dst':['1111'] * 10, 'dst_port':[80] * 10, 'content': np.random.randint(0, 1024, size=10)})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)
group = ddf.groupby(['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port'])
meta_df = make_meta(('average', 'f8'))
meta_df = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['user'], ['111'], [443]], codes=[[]] * 3, names=['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port'])
with_apply = group.content.apply(lambda s: s.mean(), meta=meta_df)
without_apply = group.content.mean()
without_apply.to_frame('average').assign(average2=without_apply) # this works

without_apply.to_frame('average').assign(average2=with_apply) # This doesn't
```

The exception is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-190777069746> in <module>
----> 1 without_apply.to_frame('average').assign(average2=with_apply)

~/virtualenvs/statistics3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in assign(self, **kwargs)
   3519         # Figure out columns of the output
   3520         df2 = 
self._meta_nonempty.assign(**_extract_meta(kwargs, nonempty=True))
-> 3521         return elemwise(methods.assign, self, *pairs, meta=df2)
   3522 
   3523     @derived_from(pd.DataFrame, ua_args=["index"])

~/virtualenvs/statistics3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in elemwise(op, *args, **kwargs)
   4273     from .multi import _maybe_align_partitions
   4274 
-> 4275     args = _maybe_align_partitions(args)
   4276     dasks = [arg for arg in args if isinstance(arg, (_Frame, Scalar, Array))]
   4277     dfs = [df for df in dasks if isinstance(df, _Frame)]

~/virtualenvs/statistics3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py in _maybe_align_partitions(args)
    162     divisions = dfs[0].divisions
    163     if not all(df.divisions == divisions for df in dfs):
--> 164         dfs2 = iter(align_partitions(*dfs)[0])
    165         return [a if not isinstance(a, _Frame) else next(dfs2) for a in args]
    166     return args

~/virtualenvs/statistics3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py in  align_partitions(*dfs)
    117     if not all(df.known_divisions for df in dfs1):
    118         raise ValueError(
--> 119             "Not all divisions are known, can't align "
    120             "partitions. Please use `set_index` "
    121             "to set the index."

ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

In my analysis I have some aggregations that can be done by constructing a  custom `Aggregator` and use it on groups. Assignment works. But some of them need some extra data to be passed so to my knowledge I can only use apply, since I cannot pass data to the aggregator functions(`chunk`, `agg`, `finalize`). From the documentation though using `Aggregator` object is preferable. Is this behaviour of apply expected?